# How does this formula describe the gradient?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, maximum-likelihood, logistic-regression

Below is the gradient of the log likelihood of the logistic regression model:

$\sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i - y_i)x_{ij}$

It is equal to

$ X^T(\alpha - y)$

Where $X$ is the design matrix, $y$ is the target vector.  And $\alpha$ = $\beta^TX$. Finally  $\beta$ consists of parameters.

How can I prove this or demonstrate this.  How does the summation describe a vector of first partial derivatives?

Comment: work out $X^T(a-y)$ element wise for a small example and then you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

In your first line 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (\alpha_i - y_i)x_{ij}$$
this is indeed a scalar, but the sum is over $i$ and there is a second index $j$. So the above scalar exists for each column $j$ of $X$.